# Congratulations to our Sheriff - Jan Doggen

Tags: discussion

Not many of you may notice necessarily but we have a Sheriff at ES SE. He is  probably first to notice every question and comment on it's quality- wall of text,etc. So many times have I had to accept his edits. Not anymore @Jan Doggen has crossed the 1000 point barrier. He can now edit as he wishes.

Well done Jan and here is hoping you enjoy your freedom in making those edits. Glad I do not have to approve your edits anymore :-)

There are others like him as well who patiently edit questions for no reward whatsoever.

FYI - I do not know anyone else who has this badge - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/deputy?userid=595

The "Deputy" badge.

Comment: I thought you meant the actual 'Sheriff' badge :P

Comment: @bon Closest is Deputy.

Comment: I suddenly see my own name mentioned in meta ????? Thanks.

Comment: @JanDoggen Suddenly ? It has been there for 2 years. Where you have been ?

Comment: @gansub Not much on meta. Or I had totally forgotten this....

Comment: @JanDoggen - well I am a Deputy now too you know...so time flies

Comment: @gansub we always fail not to congratulate him he do a huge task.

Comment: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/deputy

Comment: @JanDoggen thank you also for your work in other SE sites, I see them pop up all over the place!

Answer (score 1):

Let someone upvote one of his nice answers, as our sheriff is at 1999 reputation.

Congratulations Jan for 2k rep! and thanks for all the task you do on ES.